# How to inject powershell computed values into bash command (ran from powershell)?

Tags: bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to convert wepb images into png, using dwebp, but the parameters are from powershell:

```
foreach($ff in $f)
{
    bash -c "dwebp  $ff.name {$ff.name -replace '(.*).webp','$1.png'}"
}
```

But with what I have powershell replace is not happening. How to do this injection ?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to prepare the bash command before:

```
foreach($ff in $f) {
    $cmd = "dwebp " + $ff.name + " -o " + ($ff.name -replace '(.*).webp','$1.png')
    bash -c $cmd
}
```